# Criteria Hibernate - Erro

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0, criteria

Estou recebendo a seguinte *Exception*, analisei meu código e não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro.

É realizado a consulta e retorna os objetos, porém ao retornar, lança a *exception*.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<RespostaRequerimento> consultar(ConsultarFilter filter) throws DAOException {
    Session session =  this.getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria =  session.createCriteria(RespostaRequerimento.class);
    adicionarFiltro(filter, criteria);

    return criteria.list(); 
}

private void adicionarFiltro(ConsultarFilter filtro, Criteria criteria) {
    if(filtro !=null){
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getUsuario())){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("usuario", filtro.getUsuario()));
        }
    }
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   RequerimentoServiceImpl.consultar(ConsultaRespostaRequerimentoServiceImpl.java:102)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at $Proxy41.consultar(Unknown Source) at
>   br.com.experian.srv.respostaanaliseocorrencia.core.service.ConsultaRespostaRequerimentoServiceTest.deveConsultarPorUsuario(ConsultaRespostaRequerimentoServiceTest.java:194)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271) at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: Qual seria o código na linha 102 da classe ConsultaRespostaRequerimentoServiceImpl?

Nessa linha tem alguma variável nula.

Comment: Isaias muito obrigado. O erro não estava na criteria e sim no converter que vai tratar o retorno.  Show de bola, vlw.

Comment: Vlw, Tiago, depois marca a pergunta como resolvida.

Comment: Neste site escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Diego bom dia, como eu faço para marcar a resposta como solução. O que o Isaias mencionou solucionou o meu problema.